# Files copied to NTFS partitions in Ubuntu get deleted by Windows 8

Tags: linux, windows, ubuntu, windows-8, ntfs

I have Ubuntu 13.10 and Windows 8.1 installed, both 64-bit (dual boot). Whenever I create or copy files to any of the NTFS partitions from Ubuntu, these files get deleted once I login to Windows. When I login to Ubuntu again, the files are not there. I have seen similar questions when people hibernate windows. The problem is: **I do not hibernate. I shut down Windows properly. I have disabled fast startup option in Windows, and Fastboot from BIOS.**

The same problem occured when using Linux Mint.

How can I fix this  ?

**Update:** I have been able to find the exact event log concerning this issue in Windows Event Viewer, it says: "The file system structure on volume D: has now been repaired." and in the details section:

> EventData
>
> VolumeIdLength 2
>
> VolumeId D:
>
> RepairDetail 25008: Start
>   repair on 02/05/2014 at 20:53:12:946 25017: Processing repair verb
>   IndexEntry: 0x5000000000005, "$I30", "line-mozart.avi" Flags: 0x32,
>   0x0 26065: Deleting index entry line-mozart.avi in index
>   0x5000000000005 of file 0x2000000003498. 25009: End repair on
>   02/05/2014 at 20:53:12:946
>
> RepairDataLength 152
>
> ...

Note: "line-mozart.avi" is the name of the file that got deleted this time.

**Update 2:** I actually contacted Microsoft live support and they said it is a third party problem, not a Microsoft problem, and they will do nothing about it. Also, my question on ask Ubuntu got closed because it is an "off-topic" question, and is not an Ubuntu problem.

Now I can't work without Ubuntu and I still need Windows, can anybody help ?

Comment: Honestly, this looks like a bug in Ubuntu / [NTFS-3G](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS-3G). You may want to [report it](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found that SSD caching was the cause of the problem, and disabling it solved the issue.

In my case, a program called ExpressCache was handling SSD caching in Windows, and for some reason it doesn't work well with dual boot. I just uninstalled it the normal way you uninstall a program in Windows, and after restart everything was fixed. This however has the disadvantage of giving up the performance boost given by SSD caching. Anyway, I formatted the SSD partition and will now use it as a normal storage drive.

If anyone has a hybrid drive and faced the same problem, first find out what program is handling your SSD caching (It's probably either ExpressCache or Intel RST), then
disable SSD caching either from the program options (Intel case) or by uninstalling the program (ExpressCache case).

Until  I find an SSD caching software that deals with dual booting, I will stick with this solution.

Comment: Kudos on finding the culprit! (I'm curious: how did you find out?)

Comment: I followed Ilmari Karonen's advice and reported a bug in Launchpad and after a long discussion, the guys there opened my eyes to SSD caching problems ! You can find the bug report here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ntfs-3g/+bug/1280574